# Shortest path between two vertex

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

How we can find Shortest path between two vertex in a weighted directed acyclic graph that has positive and negative weight. in O(|V|+|E|)?

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First perform a DFS to remove all the vertex that are not accessible from the source.

Then apply the same idea as Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
dist[source]  := 0                     // Distance from source to source
stack := [source]                      // Stack that we use to remember vertices 
for each vertex v in Graph:        // Initializations
   if v != source
     dist[v]  := infinity           // Unknown distance function from source to v
     previous[v]  := undefined      // Previous node in optimal path from source
   end if 
end for

while stack is not empty:         // The main loop
  u := pop(stack)                   // take the first vertex in the stack

  for each edge (u,v) in E
     alt := dist[u] + length(u, v)
     if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
       dist[v]  := alt 
       previous[v]  := u 
     end if
     remove (u,v) from E             // That edge is useless know
     if there is no (u',v) in E      // v is now not reachable
        push(v,stack)                // store v for later
     end if
   end for

end while
return dist[], previous[]
```

Why it works: when you push a vertex you are sure that you found the shortest distance to it.

Why it is in $O(E+V)$ because each time you use an edge you remove it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Dear wece, you menas in a DAG with positive and negative weight it works ?

Comment: Yes it does. But here it is not really Dijkstra. it is really alike but the difference here is that you use the fact that there is no cycle. Hence the DAG gives you an order in which to consider the vertices so that when you consider a vertex you already know the shortest path to it. I hope I'm clear ...

Comment: Ok the problem with Dijkstra is that you need to order the vertices by the distance and that gives you a $O(E+V.log(V))$. But here the order is given by the graph. Is it clearer?

Comment: yes, it's clear.

Comment: i think the dijkstra not works with negative weight? am i right?